# Find Entity Framework Core Lastest SDK 3.1.100-preview1-014024

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Entity Framework Core Lastest Github Source Code use `3.1.100-preview1-014024` SDK.

Where can I download this version SDK?

I tried:

- Search Google & Microsoft web and only find `3.0.100` SDK
- Link : https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.0

This problem caused me to not debug run project and get error:

> Unable to locate the .NET Core SDK. Check that it is installed and that the version specified in global.json (if any) matches the installed version.

Comment: check here https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore

Comment: You can download the latest source to build on your own from their GitHub repo. [Here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/releases/tag/v3.1.0-preview1.19504.10) is a link to 3.1 preview 1. There is a build.cmd script, so it should be just as easy as downloading the source and building it

Comment: @MindSwipe thanks , it's answer! can you answer below? i'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official release build of .NET Core 3.1 preview 1 yet, you'll need to build it on your own. You can download the source from [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/releases/tag/v3.1.0-preview1.19504.10) and run the `build.cmd` (or `build.sh` if on linux) script to build the sdk. All you need to do after that is tell Visual Studio to use it